# Why is there no String.valueOf(short a);

Tags: java, casting, short

I had to cast short to a string and the only way I could do it was to concatenate an empty string with it, is this the right way?

PS, why is there no `String.valueOf(short a)`;

Comment: Why not just use the fact that it's implicitly convertible to `int`? `short x = 10; String y = String.valueOf(x);` should work fine.

Comment: Could not you simply promote short to int? `String.valueOf((int) a);` There is no precision lost in this case, is there?

Comment: @Jagger It is implicitly promoted, so there is no need to do anything. Same with `byte`.

Comment: Then even better. :)

Comment: @JonSkeet tried that, but i must have missed something and its working perfectly thanks...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the creators of the JDK didn't think that it is needed.

Given a short you can simply call `String.valueOf(int)`.

Note that even `Short.toString(short)` is implemented as `return Integer.toString((int)s, 10);`

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
 short s = 5
 String str = String.valueOf(s); // s is widened to int.
```

or

```
 String str = Short.toString(s);
```

adding a String.valueOf(short) wouldn't change much.

Answer (score 2):

`String.valueOf(short a);` is not needed because `String.valueOf(int a);` is equivalent so will be redundant in String API.

In order to use Short built in function use:

[`Short.toString(short);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html#toString%28short%29)

Also, as explained and as [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) pointed:

> Why not just use the fact that it's implicitly convertible to int? `short x = 10; String y = String.valueOf(x);` should work fine

[`String.valueOf(int);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29)