# How to write short values to text using Java data output stream?

Tags: java, file, output

I need to write values from an array of short values to a text file in their numerical from. I am using DataOutputStream and String.valueof() to accomplish this. The resulting text file is full of only zeroes separated by spaces. I am not sure how to fix this.

```
for (short s : sData) {
    dataOutputStream.writeChars(String.valueOf(s));
}
dataOutputStream.flush();
dataOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945817/why-is-there-no-string-valueofshort-a

Comment: I think it would be better to avoid short in the first place. Also there are more idiomatic apis in the jdk to write files (Files, try-with-resources,...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
short[] xs = {-10, -5, 0, 5, 10};
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new DataOutputStream(System.out));
for (short x: xs)
    out.println(x);
out.close();
```

You are calling `write(byte[])` method, which uses array of bytes - it designed for works with binary files.

You want to use text file and text format. Just add `PrintStream` as wrapper and print info like with `System.out.println()`

Comment: I did this and it still prints all zeroes

Comment: The DataOutputStream is redudant and confusing, I suggest you remove it from this example.

Comment: @Lalime In that case, your array is full of zeros.

Comment: @Lalime You can run my code in main() - and you will see it works. So, if you receives only zeros - then you array is full or zeros. You can forget to initialize it, in this case all zeros are usual behavior.

Comment: @Lalime  Please close this question as solved and Create new one with more details and code if you still have a problem.